# Why is my absolute-positioned div covering up my relative-positioned div?

Tags: css, html, css-position

I have a "ribbon" type header on the top of my website:

```
#top-wrapper {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #A1C1BE;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #59554E;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    color: #C0C0A8;
}
```

The absolute positioning is needed to make sure it occupies the complete width of the user's browser (as far as I know). However, the rest of my webpage (the main body which contains all my other divs) is hidden behind this ribbon:

```
#pagebody {
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

The only solution I have been able to find is adding a bunch of `<br>` between the end of `top-wrapper` and the start of `pagebody`.

Is there  a better way of doing this?

Comment: A fiddle or your html would help here. As someone has already pointed out absolute positioning `shouldn't` be necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment in another answer:

You can just use `width: 100%`, but make sure you remove the default gap it leaves with:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

You should also check out necolas' [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/). It includes all of this basic CSS rules you're going to need in pretty much every site :)

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely positioned elements (top-wrapper) are always on top of relative elements (pagebody), unless you do some hacky stuff with z-index (and even that is limited). What you probably want to do is move the pagebody element down just past the top-wrapper. I don't know how tall your top-wrapper is because it has no specified height. And you might not know it due to font-size differences. But overall, you simply need to add a top margin or padding to the pagebody tag, something like this:

```
margin-top:50px;
```

Comment: So there's nothing wrong with my wrapper or anything? The only way around this is a hack using margin-top once I define the height of my wrapper?

Comment: It's not a hack. That's typical use of position absolute. I think Hacky means that position absolute is an odd choice to begin with and any modification to this to fit your needs is sort of a hack since all you need to do is remove the position declaration, as well as top and left and place the entire element in the proper place in the DOM with a width 100% applied to it.

Comment: "Hacky" was used to describe use of z-index specifically, as it generally doesn't work as most people expect, and requires extra css to make it work as expected. What you really want is what others are saying (remove the absolute declaration), or as I said, shift the pagebody down using margin or padding.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning takes an element out of the normal flow.  You do not need absolute positioning to maximize width.  You do that with width:100%.

Comment: Setting `width: 100%;` leaves a small gap between the div and the browser's edge.

Comment: Set `margin: 0; padding: 0` on both `html` and `body`

Comment: @MartinodF that's exactly what I needed. If you can put that in an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @MaxMackie btw, you should probably check out something like necolas'  [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/). It includes all of this basic CSS rules you're going to need in pretty much every site :)

Comment: @MaxMackie posted the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. First, you can place your top wrapper outside the pagebody element and then just define its width as 100%.

If you have a graphic that is a ribbon and it is supposed to overlap the top of the pagebody element - as I think you are saying above - then you would use position absolute and z-index to place it above the pagebody element. Then add the proper padding-top to pagebody.

You didn't provide html so we don't really know what you're up to totally.